# Git Bash and Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, windows, command-line, git-bash

I have a Windows laptop and I just recently installed Git, choosing to use Git Bash as my terminal because I am more familiar with the commands. I've installed Ruby but when I try to run this sample program the terminal executes the 'gets' method and then the 'puts'

The following code

```
puts("Welcome to Calculator")
puts("What's the first number")
number1=gets
puts number1
```

When run from Git Bash results in this interaction with the terminal

```
2
Welcome to Calculator!
What's the first number?
2
```

instead of

```
Welcome to Calculator!
What's the first number?
2
2
```

I've tested it in a different environment and the program works fine. Is the problem caused by trying to use Git Bash to execute code on a Windows machine? Should I refrain from doing so?

Comment: So in git bash does it not print "Welcome to Calculator" until you type 2?

Comment: Yes. If I include any more 'gets' it waits for me to type them all in to display the 'puts'

Comment: Seems like @kbyte has a good answer to me. I can't think of any other reason.

Comment: Confirmation: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/208856

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

[Cmd and Git bash have a different result when run a Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668972/cmd-and-git-bash-have-a-different-result-when-run-a-python-code)

The windows terminal uses strange buffered streams. Try to force the flush like the python example.